# How to post a file to URL using java

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String addURL = "https://xxxxx.service-now.com/sys_ms_project_import.do";
    String user = "xxx";
    String pwd = "xxxx";

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    HttpPost  postMethod = new HttpPost (addURL);
    try {
        postMethod.addHeader("Authorization", "BASIC" + " " +
                new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(new String(user + ":" + pwd).getBytes("UTF-8"))));

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        String fileName = "D:\\xxxx\\xxx\\xxxxx.mpp";

        File file = new File(fileName);

        builder.addBinaryBody(
                "file",
                new FileInputStream(file),
                ContentType.APPLICATION_XML,
                file.getName()
            );

            HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
            postMethod.setEntity(multipart);  

            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postMethod);

            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();


            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I have a service now instance running and internet facing. It has a UI to import a mpp file into it. The UI is simple just having a form tag with action associated it and one file browse control and submit button. It's successfully imports file to service now when imported from UI. What it does internally I don't know.

Now my requirement is, I want to achieve same from my local machine or say from a java class on different machine.

I know I can use Apache HttpClient, to do so. But I'm not sure if this can be done. Can I do that, so that same functionality occurs as that of submitted through UI.

[Here is the UI to import file in service now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogGyD.jpg)

Here is the HTML code for above UI

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<j:jelly trim="false" xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:j2="null" xmlns:g2="null">
 <form action="sys_ms_project_import.do" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input size="41" id="importFile" name="importFile" type="file"></input>
  <input value="Import" style="width: 85px;" width="85" type="submit"></input>
 </form>
</j:jelly>
```

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: If you have an HTTP server that is accepting files as uploads, you can do it from just about any language or even the CURL command. HttpClient can post file uploads to HTTP.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: Thanks Gregg & ochi

Comment: Does anybody know how to do this?